# Project mouse 2d to 3d give wrong result when model is rotated

Tags: java, jzy3d

```
public Coord3d projectMouse(int x, int y) {
    GL2 gl = getCurrentGL();
    Coord3d p = cam.screenToModel(gl, glu, new Coord3d((float) x, (float) y, 0));
    getCurrentContext().release();
    return p;
}
```

I am using Jzy3d library, i want to get actual 3d coordinate when click with mouse. Following method works when model is at 90 degree only, if i rotate i give wrong result.
Any idea?

Comment: Please specify "wrong result": What arguments do you pass? What result do you expect? What result do you get instead? Maybe you could also tell us the arguments and the result for the success case (just to compare).

Comment: For example if 3d graph is at 0 azimuth and 90 eleveation like 2d graph. And i click at 500 hz on x axis the mouse x,y location translated to 3d model to 500 hz. if i rotate graph with azimath 20 and elevation 55. Now if i click on 500 hz, the translated values give me 800 hz in model.